# How to find devices that have all values of specific column?

Tags: sql

I have a table like this;

```
deviceId, status, time
```

**status** column only maybe `active, idle, alarm`. I want to find all deviceIds that have all status values.

So, if one device has `active, idle and alarm` value in the status column on that table, I want it's id.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`.  If you know there are three values, just do:

```
select deviceId
from t
group by deviceId
having count(distinct status) = 3;
```

If you don't know the number of values in the column, use a subquery to calculate them:

```
select deviceId
from t
group by deviceId
having count(distinct status) = (select count(distinct status) from t);
```

If you want those three in particular, add a `where` clause:

```
select deviceId
from t
where status in ('active', 'idle', 'alarm')
group by deviceId
having count(distinct status) = 3;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. So, how can I do if i dont know values of column?

Comment: Also, if I want to get top x device that fits for this query by time?

Comment: @test-big . . . This answers the question that you have asked here.  New questions should be asked as *questions* not comments.

Comment: I forgot to accept it. Sorry. No, I wonder it. I tried to solve it, But I couldn't